# @PreAuthorize annotations combining

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, annotations

I use several `@PreAuthorize`-base annotations for protecting my REST API methods.

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_A') or hasRole('ROLE_B')")
public @interface ForAorB {
}
```

and at the same time I have

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_A')")
public @interface ForA {
}
```

and

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_B')")
public @interface ForB {
}
```

My `@PreAuthorize` expressions are a bit more complex than simple `hasRole('ROLE_x)` and I would like not to doubling them both in `@ForA`, `@ForB` and in `@ForAorB`.

Whether it possible to create `@ForAorB` annotation bases on `@ForA` and `@ForB` and not expressions doubling in `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_A') or hasRole('ROLE_B')")`?

I tried this but looks like

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@ForA @ForB
public @interface ForAorB {
}
```

works actually as `@ForAandB` but not `@ForAorB`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That won't work, because annotations (at least in this case) are "additive". A single `@PreAuthorize` annotation will give you OK or NOK, and that determines the whole outcome regardless of any other possible auth annotations.

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@ForA @ForB
public @interface ForAorB {
}
```

is the same as

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_A')")
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_B')")
public @interface ForAorB {
}
```

So for `AND` it works, but you can't get it to work with `OR` except writing the `@PreAuthorize` annotation by hand.

Comment: Unfortunately, `@PreAuthorize` can't be repetitive.

Comment: @AndriyKryvtsun huh? I'm talking about why it will never work for `OR`. You can't get it to work, so write the annotation by hand.